# Как сделать header как на примере?

Tags: html, css

Всем добрый день!

Решил попробовать сделать нечто подобное, но так и не придумал как это сделать..
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как бы картинка налезает на треугольник снизу + у этого треугольника красные линии. Подскажите как это сделать?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Servera</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="nav-top">
            <div class="container">
                <p>Вход / Регистрация</p>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <nav class="nav-bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <img src="" alt="Loyal Servers">         
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main class="container">
      <h3>title</h3>
    </main>

</body>
</html>
```

Если можно, вот на этом примере [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gp3vqgjv/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе нужен clip-path

Вот ссылка на статью про него https://getinstance.info/articles/css/making-sense-of-clip-path/

и вот сделанный твой header  https://jsfiddle.net/gp3vqgjv/4/

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 95%, 75% 95%, 50% 100%, 25% 95%, 0 95%);
```

Comment: Круто! Спасибо! То что нужно!